# Scheduled task of User profile updation - best practice

Tags: development, user-profile, user-profile-service, scheduled-tasks

I have wrote a C# code which will update two custom attributes of User Profile(for all users). Values for those two resides in different database(not in active directory).

We need to run that c# code daily(every night). So which method is the best way to go.
        - Windows service or
        - Web service or
        - WCF or any other way.

Just want to know what is the best practice for **updating user profile** (automatically from other database) on daily basis.

Note: Our sharepoint architecture is a multi-tier and both Application and content database are in different servers.

Suggestion please. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in a database why not use the BCS to create an External Content Type? Then create a secondary import connection in the User Profile Service and have the properties updated when the Synchronization Timer Job runs?

If not then you could just run it as a Windows scheduled job. Heck, you could even ditch the C# for PowerShell.

Comment: Excellent! Just now I read about those BCS in this video - http://www.microsoft.com/resources/technet/en-us/office/media/video/video.html?cid=stc&from=mscomSTC&videoid=ede7d855-035c-47a9-9492-1c2a23614a4a Thank you so much